# In simple class, not able to open file in Assets folder to load to array in Android app

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I want to read from my simple java class "MyContent", and there is a static method with no arguments, as once you call the variable inside, it will do the codes inside the static method. I am trying to add code into it by reading the files in Assets folder and put into list so that the data adaptor will read it.

MyContent class:

```
public class MyContent extends Application {

public static final List<Element> ITEMS = new ArrayList<Element>();

private static Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public static final Map<String, Element> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, Element>();
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
static {

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("data.csv");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader((inputStream));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader((inputStreamReader));
        String tt="";
        while ((tt=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            MyContent.addItemElement(MyContent.createElement(tt));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

The problem is that the AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); can't be static, but the InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("data.csv"); I need to put them into the static method, can anyone tell me how to deal with this issue?

Comment: It is not a good idea to put heavy task, e.g. reading data, inside static initialiser, because this may cause the class loading failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAssets()` need application `context` initialised upfront before you can] call it. Below code flow should be able to achieve your objective:

```
public class MyContent extends Application {

    public static final Map<String, Element> ITEM_MAP;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, Element>();
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("data.csv");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader((inputStream));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader((inputStreamReader));
            String tt="";
            while ((tt=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                MyContent.addItemElement(MyContent.createElement(tt));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit 1

Inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`, remember to add your app class under tag `application`, e.g.

```
<application
        android:name=". MyContent"
   ...
</application>
```

Comment: I can' use this in the activities. This is just a regular java class which will load the file and put into the list.My issue right now is I want to show the file content to the main activity .but if I do this in main activity onCreate, then I click add button to another activity and add something then come back, the main activity will reload again, which will add to list again..

Comment: Maybe I will try to load everything in the main activity  everytime and once I have added something I will write to the "data.csv"file?

Comment: This code snippet is not inside `Activity`, it is inside `Application` which is the starting point of your app.

Comment: Note `MyContent extends Application`.

Comment: So even a simple java class will be able to define an onCreate method which will be recognized by the Android app?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application for more details about `Application` class. It is not a SIMPLE java class but a class having lifecycle management about your Android applications.

Comment: it didn't work, maybe I am not good at describing my issue, but I will accept this answer for your effort in helping me solve the issue.

Comment: The class that extends `Application` is the very first class that will be called by Android framework, inside the `Application` lifecycle method `onCreate()` you can do some initialisation jobs. For your case, you can access `ITEM_MAP` by `MyContent.ITEM_MAP`. See my edits above.